# How to get FCM onMessageReceived event in activity without PendingIntent

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement pub/sub in my app, for that server send notification in specific event, I will do some modification on data which is display in my activity

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, provide the code you created.

Comment: I implement only FCM in my app

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onMessageReceived()` doesn't need PendingIntent to be call. It will always call if you have correct setup. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) provide the data type you should sent to FCM server

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> 1. Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
> 2. Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

If you would like to always trigger use just data message so it will always trigger the `onMessageReceived()`.If you try to use data-message and notification-message together the `onMessageReceived()` will not get trigger when your app is in background.

Just do anything you would like to do such as save to database, sharedPeference etc inside your `onMessageReceived()`

So how you sent to the activity?

Use Broadcast Receiver here is how you sent a broadcast receiver in your case you will like to put it inside your `onMessageReceived()` so anytime you received a new notification this code will help you sent the data to the specific activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Use anything you like");
intent.putExtra("data","The data you receive");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your activity register it in your `onStart()`

```
registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver,new IntentFilter("must match the intent filter parameter"));
```

Here is how you handle your data

```
class broadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Your data",intent.getData());
    }
}
```

**Note:** your intent filter parameter must match the intent parameter you set in your `onMessageReceived()`

If your app never received data from the FCM this answer will be useless since your question still unclear this is the best I can do for you.